# Cypress - Overlay not popping up when button is clicked

Tags: react-native, cypress, touchablewithoutfeedback

Description:
I am currently trying to write an automated test that involves clicking on a button within a navigation bar. The expected behavior is that an overlay that contains more links would pop up, as seen in this video here: https://www.screencast.com/t/55vkmhY8msjt

When testing this manually within a Chrome browser (which is recorded in the aforementioned video), the overlay pops up as expected.

But when executing the automated Cypress test within the Cypress browser, Cypress is able to locate the element and successfully click it, but the overlay does not pop up.
When I manually click on the button within the Cypress browser, the overlay does not pop up.

Video of bug being reproduced:
https://www.screencast.com/t/iSn8suNHa
It's hard to tell, but after the test execution finishes, I am manually trying to click on the button with my mouse.

I've tried several things:

```
cy.get(selector).click({force:true})
cy.get(selector).trigger('click')
cy.get(selector).invoke('click')
```

Extra information:
This button was recently re-implemented using React Native's TouchableWithoutFeedback
There are no errors being thrown in Cypress, no errors in the console.

Versions
Cypress 7.5.0
Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93

Can somebody please suggest some other steps I can try?

Comment: We have discovered there to be a bug in our app, which we have resolved, and the Cypress test is now working.